# OpenAM: How to restrict users to a realm

Tags: openam, realm, opensso

We have concept of Operators(Employees, Merchants, Billers) and Subscribers in our applications. We have installed OpenAM 12.0 with default configuration to test the setup. We are thinking of setting up realms hierarchy

```
/Top Level Realm
    Operators
    Subscribers
```

When we add a user to a realm via "Subscribers"->"Subjects"->"Users"->"Add", the added user also appears in "Operators" realm. Is there a way to make sure this user is isolated to Subscribers realm?

Comment: OpenAM consumes identity information from a data store. This is configured in the data store section. If you create users within the same container (from LDAP server point of view) then of course OpenAM will consume it in every realm which has the same 'baseDN' set in the data store configuration

Comment: Thanks @BernhardThalmayr, that seems to be the issue. I got same answer from forge-rock forum as well. https://forgerock.org/topic/how-to-restrict-users-to-a-realm/#post-3340